# Get remote tcp connection's ip address in java?

Tags: java, networking, tcp, ip

I've used the well-known and excellent [Knock Knock server tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html) as a way to learn java networking. I have tried to find out the ip address of the connected client using socket.getInetAddress(), but it always returns the ip of my router, 192.168.1.254, presumably because the connection is bouncing through there. Is there any way to get the correct ip of the remote client that's connected to a tcp socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ServerSocket sSock;
Socket cSock;

sSock = new ServerSocket(port_number);
cSock = sSock.accept();
System.out.println(cSock.getRemoteSocketAddress()+" connected\n");
```

it will print whole socket address of the connected client like this:

> /127.0.0.1:1878 connected

Comment: Thanks, this returns the same address as getInetAddress(), but includes the port. It still comes up as 192.168.1.254, but I think that's because I was trying to connect to my external ip from inside the same network. Basically in the end I'm connecting to localhost but in a roundabout way. I was expecting it to return the value of my external ip. Also relax Nikhar, I'm new here. You got your accept.

Comment: it will not give an external ip, if both server and client are on the same machine or same network. try this with your friend, then he needs to connect to your server by your external ip..and lol..no its just that i saw your other question, and even there you didnt accept any answer...i am also new, your acceptance will help me and the community..well no probs.

Comment: I didn't even know there was an accept button until you complained that I "never accepted answers". :-) Actually I am pretty sure my original code would have given the correct answer (minus the port number) if it was a friend connecting from outside.